# Complex SQL query in order retrieve the available beds in a given timeframe matched to rooms in a reservation system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing a reservation system where I need to select all available beds in a given time range and match them to the rooms they're in.

Somehow my query seems to partially work, but unfortunately it returns some wrong rows. As can be seen in the fiddle for example no beds in room 1 should be returned due the **WHERE NOT (ro.status = 0)** clause, because room_status for room 1 is set to 0 (room not available due cleaning for example).

The tables used are:

bed (contains all beds, matched to rooms with FK room_id)
room (contains all rooms, rooms can be disabled eq. for cleaning purpoes by a room_status field. if a room is disabled, all associated beds are unavailable)
reservation (contains all reservations)
reservation_bed (matches a reservation to certain beds booked).

My query looks like:

```
SELECT b.id AS bed_id, b.name AS bed_name, b.room_id AS room_id, ro.name AS room_name, ro.status AS room_status
FROM bed b
LEFT JOIN room ro ON ro.id = b.id
WHERE NOT (ro.status = 0) AND b.id NOT IN(SELECT rb.bed_id FROM reservation_bed rb
LEFT JOIN reservation r ON r.id = rb.reservation_id
WHERE r.end BETWEEN str_to_date('$start', '%d.%m.%Y') AND str_to_date('$end', '%d.%m.%Y') OR
  str_to_date('$start', '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN r.start AND r.end
ORDER BY b.room_id
```

SQLFiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cca72/4

Thank you in advance

Comment: The `left join`s would seem to be unnecessary because the `where` clause converts them to inner joins.  In addition, I'm removing the SQL Server tag, because the syntax is clearly MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yeah thats the point, i basically need to match each bed to it's room.name and room.status. After that im gonna sort out the beds, which are not available because of a ro.status=0  or beeing unvailable between $start and $end date

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your problem is the date comparison.  You are comparing dates as strings.  Although you shouldn't do this, it is alright if the format is YYYY-MM-DD.  Instead, compare the dates correctly, using *date* variables:

```
WHERE r.end BETWEEN str_to_date('$start', '%d.%m.%Y') AND str_to_date('$end', '%d.%m.%Y') OR
      str_to_date('$start', '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN r.start AND r.end
```

Actually, rather than inserting strings into the query, you should insert parameters, and you can give these a type of date -- eliminating the need for type conversions in the query itself.  (And, this is a good practice to avoid SQL injection and to prevent run-time errors in the database.)

Your query may have other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, bad mistake..

i did

```
LEFT JOIN room ro ON ro.id = b.id
```

but this should have been

```
LEFT JOIN room ro ON ro.id = b.room_id
```